# Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: ios, uiwebview, afnetworking, deprecated

I have uploaded app in Testflight and got letter with this content:
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

I refactored my code but still I have UIWebView+AFNetworking.h file in the project.

I updated pods, now I have AFNetworking (3.2.1)

Say me please, how to remove UIWebView from AFNetworking also.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy all AFNetworking source files to a folder in your main target
2. Remove the AFNetworking entry from your Podfile and run `Pod Install`
3. Remove the files UIWebView+AFNetworking.*
4. If you use Objective C, you might need to change the import syntax from `#import <AFNetworking/[FileName].h>` to: `#import "[FileName].h"` in some of your files

Comment: if i copy AFNetworking files in my target directory and then install that pod, i will have double content. No? Please say me why to copy it?

Comment: The idea is that you DON'T use the pod, and instead of the pod you just copy all the needed files to your main target. This way you can remove the UIWebView extension without causing build errors.

Answer (score 0):

## Update or delete?

I faced the same issue. I did not use UIWebView in the code anywhere but checks out two external libraries that had UIWebView references. So I had to remove the references.

**How to find out which external library is using UIWebView?**

```
$ grep -r "UIWebView" .  //Rookie mistake. Don't forget the . <-(dot)
```

It will give a list of libraries which has UIWebView references in them.

**I found 2 libraries in my case?**

1. AFNetworking
2. TwitterKit

### How did I remove the references?

- UIWebView

It seems the new version has removed the UIWebView references so I bumped the AFNetworking library in Podfile to the latest version.

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0'
```

- TwitterKit

TwitterKit also has references to UIWebView. But the problem was that there is no new version available and they have officially discontinued the development of this library two years ago.

So I had to remove TwitterKit from the project. For that, I removed TwitterKit dependency from Podfile